# How to use SEH in 64-bit assembly with MASM64?

Tags: assembly, visual-studio-2017, x86-64, masm, seh

I'm trying to learn how to use structured exception handling (SEH) in a 64-bit Windows executable compiled with MASM64.

So far, let's take this simple example. My test goal is to suppress invalid operation exception in this function:

```
.data

holdPrevRSP QWORD ?

.code

ExceptionFrm PROC
    ; Exception handler?

    mov     rsp, [holdPrevRSP]

    ; int       3       ; tried to invoke debugger manually

    add     rsp, 100h
    pop     r15
    pop     r14
    pop     r13
    pop     r12
    pop     rsi
    pop     rsi
    pop     rbp
    pop     rbx
    ret
ExceptionFrm ENDP



TestFunc PROC FRAME:ExceptionFrm

    ; Define prolog:

    ; Need to save:
    ;   RBX, RBP, RDI, RSI, RSP, R12, R13, R14, and R15

    push    rbx
    .pushreg rbx
    push    rbp
    .pushreg rbp
    push    rdi
    .pushreg rdi
    push    rsi
    .pushreg rsi
    push    r12
    .pushreg r12
    push    r13
    .pushreg r13
    push    r14
    .pushreg r14
    push    r15
    .pushreg r15

    .ENDPROLOG

    ; really primitive way to restore RSP
    ; i know it's not multi-threaded safe!
    ; It's just for this test...
    mov     [holdPrevRSP], rsp

    ; define home stack for this function
    sub     rsp, 100h


    db 62h, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0       ; should raise invalid opcode exception



    ; Epilog
    add     rsp, 100h
    pop     r15
    pop     r14
    pop     r13
    pop     r12
    pop     rsi
    pop     rsi
    pop     rbp
    pop     rbx
    ret
TestFunc ENDP

END
```

I guess my issue is that I don't fully understand what `FRAME:` keyword does.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 to run this test. When I step through this code with the debugger, when I step over the `invalid opcode` the process throws a debugger exception in some other unrelated location in the process.

I then tried to put a breakpoint inside my `ExceptionFrm` but it never gets called.

So what am I doing wrong here?